# Poll to server on background to implement push notifications Android & WinPhone

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, push-notification

I need a easy solution to implement push notifications on Android and  Windows phone. 
Lets supouse that battery consumption is not a problem, and i prefer implementing this for my own insted of using some third-party library.
So, the most easy way is to do busy-waiting to the server, asking for a new notification.
Is this posible in Android and Windows Phone? A service running in background, even if the user is not using the application (but has started it already), polling a webservice on the server, asking for a new event?

Comment: The most easy way, is using a 3rd party library. If you dont want this, don't look for the most easy way.

Comment: Ok, forget the most easy way. My question is if this is even posible, the busy waiting to the server in background. If this is possible, i will do it. Otherwise, god help me.

Comment: Why do you need to check for updates anywhere? Push changes from the server to the phone when a change happens. Otherwise assume nothing has changed. Similarly, push changes from phone to server, if no message has been received assume nothing happened in the phone. Why do you need to proactively check?

Comment: The problem is pushing changes from the server to the phone. I am not using any library neither plataform-based tecnology. So, i am implementing the push method you say using just calls to server webservice's. But to do this, i need to be sure that for both plataforms, its posible to have a thread on background getting gps position and sending it to server.

Comment: You can just open a socket connection and push messages through that.